# Buscador de palabras clave NO reconoce correctamente los caracteres especiales

Tags: javascript, string, input

En Javascript he creado un buscador de palabras para articulos de una web; pero tengo problemas con el **signo de interrogación (?)** parece ser que Javascript no lo reconoce de forma correcta porque al añadir **"más de 2"** me genera error. El siguiente codigo es un ejemplo del problema que tengo:

```
let a = "How? what?"
let b = "How? what?";
if(b.toLowerCase().search(a.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
    alert(true)
}else{
    alert(false)
}
// Resultado: FALSE
```

El resultado es "False" a pesar que es igual; pero:

```
let a = "How?"
let b = "How? what?";
if(b.toLowerCase().search(a.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
    alert(true)
}else{
    alert(false)
}
// Reusltado: TRUE
```

Aqui la respuesta es "True". ¿Porque se genera este problema y que solución me pueden ofrecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando el método [.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) para buscar coincidencias, pero usa una [expresión regular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular) donde el caracter `?` tiene un significado especial.

En este caso, es mejor el método [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) para que la comparación se haga directamente con cadenas:

```js
let a = "How? what?"
let b = "How? what?";
if(b.toLowerCase().indexOf(a.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
    console.log(true)
}else{
    console.log(false)
}
// Resultado: true

let c = "How?"
let d = "How? what?";
if(d.toLowerCase().indexOf(c.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
    console.log(true)
}else{
    console.log(false)
}
// Resultado: true
```

Comment: Muchas gracias..!!  En primera instancia funciona, lo voy a probar con el codigo completo que cree para ver como le va..  Nuevamente gracias por responder y por ser el unico usuario que se ha tomado la molestia en ayudarme, ya van 2..!!

Comment: Y una ultima pregunta en caso que quisiera seguir usando el **search()** que solución me podrias ofrecer antes este metodo..

Comment: @nicolamendoza, tendrías que escapar todos los caracteres que tienen significado especial en expresiones regulares, anteponiendo una diagonal invertida, por ejemplo: `if(b.toLowerCase().search(a.toLowerCase().replaceAll('?', '\\?')))`

Comment: Esta bien, gracias por el aportes.!!